# HTML table-like layout with <div>'s?

Tags: layout, html

I'm trying to create a layout like this:

```
[Left Area][Row 1]
[         ][Row 2]
[         ] ...
```

Rows 1,2 etc. should stay below each other and never go under [Left Area]

I tried to make [Left Area] and Rows area into div's with "display:inline", and it works, but only until I'm trying to separate individual rows - then [Row 2] either sits next to [Row 1] or goes under [Left Area].

```
<div>
<div style="float:left;display:inline">Left Left Left</div>
<div style="display:inline">
    <div>First First First</div>
    <div>Second Second Second</div>
</div>
</div>
Below Below Below
```

Comment: can you show sample HTML and the corresponding CSS to organize these DIVs as table?

Comment: Ok, but my HTML is obviously flawed.

Answer (score 0):

From the little information you have here it is hard to tell what you are really looking for. But check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xgzuc/) to see if it is what you're looking for.